# Not getting length of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am working with AngularJS a very new in this. I need to get length of a input box and it shows me "0". My code is shown below

```
var valueOfMybox=  $("#mybox").val().length
```

I fill the box and alert `valueOfMybox`.  It shows me 0 every time  .

Comment: make a plunker and post the snippet.we can then help you better

Comment: check for value first `alert($("#mybox").val())` see if it gives you something

Answer (score 2):

Don't use jQuery, for one.
You need to bind the value of your input box to scope, then you can access the value of the input box from your controller.

HTML, something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" />
```

Controller:

```
var valLength = $scope.myText.length;
```

Here is a demo of an input that displays the length of it's contents:
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pkDFY6KDDkqCVrFDdLyt?p=preview)